# How to sort a Hashmap in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, sorting, hashmap, jstl

I implemented a Hashmap in JSP sometimes back now I need to sort it.

How can it be done in JSP?

```
<jsp:useBean id="myHashMAp" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

<c:set target="${myHashMAp}" property="${someProperty}" value="${valueData}"/>
```

Now how to sort 'myHashMAp' ?

**NOTE:** I don't want to use Scriptlet and it can't be done in databean.

Formation of Hashmap is required at JSP level.

Comment: You can't sort a `HashMap` or any other `Map` either (`TreeMap` is self sorting).

Comment: @Kayaman that is what I supposed while impelmenting map but recently we got a case where keys are "1,7 and 12"  but the map show entries in the sequence of (12,1,7) ... why is that so?

Comment: A view can't do much if the model is wrong in first place. Just fix the model so the view can present it decently. Wrap if necessary the wrong model in the right model. "Can't be done" is a non-argument.

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap cannot be sorted, you have to use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) like Brijesh suggested (Your elements have to implement Comparable or you have to provide a compartor during construction).

If you just want insertion order you could also use a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). No compartor is needed for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use **TreeMap**, like

```
Map<Type, Type> newmap = new TreeMap<Type, Type>(your_hash_map_variable);
```

For more details, refer [**this**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).